# Is it possible to upgrade the RAW plugin in Photoshop without having to upgrade Photoshop?

Tags: raw, photoshop

I've been happy with Photoshop CS2 for a long while now, but I've recently upgraded my camera, and I've found that the RAW plugin I've got doesn't support the updated version of the RAW files. Is it possible to upgrade to a later RAW plugin, without having to fork out for a later edition of Photoshop?

Comment: As far as I know Nick is correct, the RAW plugin is version tied and not available stand-alone. However, bear in mind that you probably can do the upgrade from CS2 to CS5 for the lower cost. Worth it, in my opinion, for all the other features they added for photographers, especially the content-aware features which are worth the price of admission alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no. The interface between ACR and Photoshop has changed a couple of times over the years. When a change happens, Ps can only use versions of ACR up to when the change took place.

That limits the possibilities for updates, but *some* updates are still possible. Adobe has a [download page](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/product.jsp?product=39&platform=Windows) with updates for the various versions of Ps.

That said, chances are that it won't be sufficient. The most recent update to ACR for CS2 is still pretty old, so even though you can probably update somewhat from what you're using now, it still won't be enough newer to let you load files from a brand new camera.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately not. Adobe in their wisdom decided to force you to upgrade Photoshop if you splash out on a new camera model.

You may want to download the free [Adobe RAW converter](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=4802), and convert the images to DNG format, which will be compatible with Photoshop.

Comment: I feared this may be the case (and I'd already got the DNG converter from Adobe), but you never know, there might be a way somehow. I thought I'd ask here after discussing on the site's chat area at http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211/photo-se